# Besides looking dumping $PSVersionTable and dumping the variable and env "PS-Drives", what else can I do to compare PowerShell environments?

Tags: powershell

Besides looking dumping `$PSVersionTable` and dumping the variable and env "PS-Drives", what can I do to compare PowerShell environments?

Here's the problem:

- I have very similar machines running Microsoft Windows Server 2012
- `$PSVersionTable` dumps as:

  ```
  Name                           Value
  ----                           -----
  PSVersion                      4.0
  WSManStackVersion              3.0
  SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
  CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34014
  BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17090
  PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
  PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
  ```

  on the server that works, and

  ```
  Name                           Value
  ----                           -----
  PSVersion                      4.0
  WSManStackVersion              3.0
  SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
  CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
  BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
  PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
  PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
  ```

  on the server that I'm having a problem with.
- Not a whole not of difference in a base `variable:` drive.
- Reasonable differences in `env:` contents
- And they both have ExecutionPolicy set to RemoteSigned.

So the differences are in the *minor* version. But the first server will run the Animal classes example that comes with the [PSClass deployment](http://psclass.codeplex.com/), and the second won't.

And I've traced it in the debugger to the second call to `Attach-PSScriptMethod`, whether in a debugger or not, the second server just hangs on that call.

---

**Update:** Just got a change to update my first server to Build 6.3.30319.34209, the same minor version as the second (and the same CLRVersion). Now the example breaks as well. Looks like Microsoft broke the PSClass library.

I hope not too many scripts rely on the OO model used there, because if they broke the simple example, they could as well have broken heavier code.

I still can't even get it to dump out the *problem* it has

Comment: This is a close one, but you will probably get better results on Stack Overflow. While Powershell is generally on-topic here, this question is particularly code-centric in a way that I think makes it appropriate for either site.

Comment: Thanks, @RyanRies. I was thinking similarly, which is why I mainly asked whether there is a script or a tool to verbosely dump the factors that play into a powershell environment.

Comment: I'm running the [latest PS 5.0 preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45883) and observe the same behavior. In my case it's loops forever in the`Attach-PSScriptMethod`, where no loops exist at all.

Comment: @beatcracker, That makes sense, because an update to my first server did the same thing. Check my update. So the CLRVersion or the minor build version seems to have something to do with it.

Comment: @beatcracker, it looks like in overriding the ToString method, something in PSClass's override mechanism tries to call ToString and you get a recursion issue.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Powershell version 4.0 and above you can use $PSVersionTable. Anything less than version 4.0, you would need to use `Get-Host`

[Determine Installed Powershell Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version)